# Question about Pollicott-Yuri's proof of Rudolph theorem

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

On the book 
[Dynamical System and Ergodic theory](http://books.google.cl/books?id=pQm5yAokj8cC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false/) by Pollicott and Yuri there is a proof of the Rudolph x2 x3 theorem (page 153). It looks very clean in comparison with the original proof but I didn't understand when they calculated the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(f|T^{-n}\mathcal{B})$. They used the notation $$T'(x) = \frac{d\mu T}{d\mu} (x)$$ for the Radon-Nykodim derivative but $\mu T$ is not even a measure because $T$ is not invertible. So, I didn't understand the notations or I'am missing something.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How about the induced measure $E \to \mu(T^{-1}E)$? I've seen it written as $\mu T^{-1}$, at least.

Comment: but in this context 
$\mu$ is $T$ invariant so $\mu T^{-1}=\mu$ hence 
$\frac{d\mu T^{-1}}{d\mu}=1$.

Comment: Well, that makes sense for ergodic theory. Sorry, I don't know, and I don't have a copy of the text or a readable excerpt on Google Books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $T'$ suggests that $\mu T$ is the subadditive functional $B\mapsto\mu(T(B))$. 
Under some continuity hypothesis, versions of Radon-Nykodym theorem still hold in this context.

See the paper *A Radon-Nikodym theorem for capacities*, Siegfried Graf, Journal für die Reine und Angewandte Mathematik 320 (1980) 192-214.